# Helicon ISAPI Rewrite is processing Rewrite Rules for httpd.conf but not .htaccess

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, .htaccess, rewrite, isapi

We have Helicon ISAPI Rewrite 3 installed on our Windows 2003 Web server.  The RewriteRules work fine in the global file located in the httpd.conf file.  The server serves several Web sites and we were hoping to create RewriteRules to apply to specific Web sites.  In the IIS Properties for each Web site there exists a separate tab for ISAPI_Rewrite pointing to the .htaccess file for that Web site.  No rules applied to the .htaccess files work.  Any ideas why the .htaaccess files have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Check NTFS permissions on .htaccess files and make sure you are not using the Lite version of ISAPI_Rewrite.

In the .htaccess files themselves make sure you have

```
RewriteEngine on
```

at the top of each file.

Edit to add:
Put these lines in your httpd.conf file and reload the service.  They will create error and rewriter log files.  Checking the event viewer might also shed some light on the issue.

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
LogLevel debug
```

Comment: NTFS Persmissions look good, RewriteEngine is on.  I believe it is not the Lite version, how can we be sure?

Comment: Beyond the installation file name which contains an 'l' rathern than an 'f' I can't find any clear differences between the two beyond functionality.  Added an edit to my answer for another trying to check.